# I want to make a transition effect but how? Help me

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, effects, transform-orientation

I want to make an effect like I put the images, but no matter how much research I did, I couldn't find it. Anyone know how to do this?

Link: [https://vimeo.com/665069736?embedded=true&source=vimeo_logo&owner=131946355[enter](https://vimeo.com/665069736?embedded=true&source=vimeo_logo&owner=131946355%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REROH.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the cube splash effect from 9 to 14 seconds in?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if u are satisfied with this https://youtube.com/shorts/UC7j0Uy3OHA?feature=share i can offer a solution. If you are looking for perfection...maybe better wait and hope for another answer.

Comment: I'm talking about the cube effect, right. I don't know how to do it in blender. Can I find the tutorial for the Geometry nodes part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start with this "basic" setup and fine tune it:

[image]

So basically the grid/cube/instances are just instancing the cubes on the ground.
I made a cube "controller" which i keyframed so that it can control the scale and the noise movement.
Via the object info/proximity/multiply/map range and can control the scaling of the boxes on the "right side" (depends of course on your viewport view) and by calculating the difference between the controller and each position of the vertices i know on what side (right or left) the cubes should be scaled. So this differentiation is simply done by the less than node. A boolean math node (not) just inverts that - so i know it is the other side.
The branch from the noise texture to the set position node just offsets the cubes on the z-axis, and depending on the proximity to the controller, move them down the their original position again (that's what the mix node does).

result can look like this (of course you have to add lights/camera etc):

[image]

Comment: Chris, you saved me a lot of trouble. Thank you so much. I'll try the nodes right away.

Comment: @Cris, thank you so much for your help, but I still need help. I created the nodes and the image appeared. But how do I create the animation. The control object doesn't work. Sorry for not understanding knots. Maybe you explained, but I didn't understand.
https://imageup.me/help

Comment: upload your blend file and i will take a look

Comment: https://we.tl/t-hj89eQy2me?utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_05&utm_source=sendgrid&utm_medium=email&trk=TRN_TDL_05

Comment: you made all perfectly right - but the controller has to be a mesh - you made an empty. Then it works. Here your updated file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Vvs0Z7xz" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Vvs0Z7xz/) result: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvZ6p.gif -> that's why i wrote "create a cube as controller" ;) -> the proximity node only works with geometry/mesh, not with empties (who have no geometry)

Comment: pls click on the checkmark left of my answer, if my answer helped you, thx.

Comment: You are a perfect person. Thank yooooouuuuu :)

Comment: you are welcome